# How to kill a command executed from a script?

Tags: shell-script, process, kill

I would like to start a tcpdump in my own script an after some time I would like to kill it again. How can I access the PID from the tcpdump. I tried it with $$ , but this only kills the script.

```
if [[ $TIMEEND != $Zeit ]];then
                        echo "tcpdump started"
                        sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -w /media/usbhd-sd[b-c]1/abfrage2.pcap &
                        pid1=$!
                        break
                        #sudo umount /dev/sdb1
                else
                        sudo kill $pid1
                        echo "autodump stopped"
                fi
```

This is the output when i grep tcpdump so I think it's not possible to use pidof and pkill.

[image]

I tried to do it with awk

```
  pid1=$(ps -eo pid,args|awk '/abfrage2/ && ! /awk/{print $1}')
                            echo $pid1 >> /tmp/test.txt
                            sudo kill $pid1
```

When i directly use the command for pid, it finds the pid but it doesn't execute the kill.

I think I have to overthink my code a little bit. I inmport the time from the config file, then I check if the starttime is the same and if it is it should also check if it isn't the endtime. Then it should execute the tcpdump as long as it isn't the endtime. When it arrives the endtime it should kill the the tcpdump. I know it's not the best solution, but it would be nice to get it working with something like that.

```
   #!/bin/sh
source /media/usbhd-sdb1/config.conf
pluggedin=true
echo $TIMESTART
echo $TIMEEND
echo $$
echo $Zeit
echo $$ >> /tmp/test.txt
while [ $pluggedin ];do
        Zeit=$(date +"%T")
        if [[ $TIMESTART == $Zeit ]];then
                if [[ $TIMEEND != $Zeit ]];then
                        echo "tcpdump started"
                        sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -w /media/usbhd-sd[b-c]1/abfrage2.pcap &
                        #sudo umount /dev/sdb1
                else
                        pid1=$(ps -eo pid,args|awk '/abfrage2/ && ! /awk/{print $1}')
                        echo $pid1 >> /tmp/test.txt
                        sudo kill -9 $pid1
                        echo "autodump stopped"
                fi

        else
        echo "tcpdump not yet started"
        fi
done
```

Comment: If you know in advance how long you want the `tcpdump` to run for you should consider the `timeout` command which will do what you want without you having to try to reinvent it all

Answer (score 3):

If i understand you want to run the tcpdump for some time and kill it. You can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -w /media/usbhd-sd[b-c]1/abfrage2.pcap &
PID=$!
sleep 20
sudo kill -9 $PID
exit 0
```

The `$!` will give you the pid of the command launched. To kill it you invoke the `kill [Signal] [PID]` to kill the tcpdump command.

Kindly note that we run the tcpdump in [background](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html) with the `&` at the end of the command else the tcpdump will continue executing in the [foreground](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html). The `exit 0` will ensure that the script is killed at the end.

[Proof of concept]

```
bash -x a.sh
+ PID=21988
+ sleep 10
+ tcpdump -i eth0 -w abfrage2.pcap
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
+ kill -9 21988
+ exit 0
```

[Alternatively]

As suggested by Eric you can also do it with [timeout](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3592/execute-a-command-with-a-timeout) command

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout 10s tcpdump -i eth0 -w abfrage2.pcap
exit 0
```

Comment: Why is the answer down voted?

Comment: If you know you want to run for a fixed period the `timeout` command will do a lot of the work for you, and will exit before the timeout period if the command exits earlier than that, unlike sleeping for a fixed period

Answer (score 1):

Your `sudo tcpdump` command should go into the background by appending an ampersand `&` to the line:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -w /media/usbhd-sd[b-c]1/abfrage2.pcap &
```

The line `pid1=$!` will put the PID of the `sudo tcpdump` command into variable `pid1`

If you want to kill the process you should use:

```
sudo kill $pid1
```

You used `$$` which represents the PID of the current running process.

Since you are using this within another script, which you probably will call multiple times, all subsequential runs does not have a utilized `pid1` variable.

To get the PID in this variable you can use:

```
pid1=$(pidof tcpdump)
```

in the `else` section of your script.

Or simply use:

```
sudo pkill tcpdump
```

Assuming that you only have one copy of tcpdump running.

One other thing you need to take care off. Every time you call your script and the `$TIMEEND` does not equals to `$Zeit` it will start another `tcpdump` process. A better solution would be:

```
if [ "$TIMEEND" != "$Zeit" ] && [ "$(pidof tcpdump)" == "" ]
```

which will test both the time requirement and the existence of a `tcpdump` process.

Comment: So I tried this, but it does terminate the script above and it also doesn't kill the tcpdump. What also could be important is that it is used in a if-else clause--> check updated post

Comment: Do not downvote answers if the correct question is not asked... See updated answer to clarify what is problably wrong.

Comment: I didn't downvote anything. I'm thankful for every help.

Comment: @Lambert Totally agree !! @ apuboard did you run the script since both mine and Lambert suggestion works :) Kindly check the update. Besides, please do not modify your original codes in the question, please do it whithin an update secion.

Comment: @apuboard, apologies for my assumption then. nevertheless, see the updated answer for a probable cause.

Comment: @Lambert So I tried it like that whti running it in the background and without, neither has worked, is it possible to just read it from the ps and awk the pid and then kill it?

Comment: Sure, consider using `pid1=$(ps -eo pid,args|grep abfrage2|grep -v grep)|cut -d ' ' -f1` as first statement within your `else` section.

Comment: Or using `awk`: `pid1=$(ps -eo pid,args|awk '/abfrage2/ && ! /awk/{print $1}')`

Comment: Or consider using the approach of @pqnet and use a pidfile instead: `echo $! > /tmp/tcpdump-abfrage2.pid` and `pid1=$(</tmp/tcpdump-abfrage2.pid)`

Comment: @Lambert I tried it, but the kill doesn't get executed.

Comment: Try to change the `sudo kill $pid1` to `echo sudo kill $pid1` to see what it tries to do (or use `bash -x myscript.sh` to see debugging messages). Perhaps you need to call `kill` with the `-9` argument to forcibly kill the processes (`sudo kill -9 $pid1`).

Comment: @Lambert so I found my whole structure of the script doesn't really work throught debugging. If I dont add &, it is starting the tcpdump and it blocks the whole script.

Comment: @Lambert I just found out that you can't use && [ "$(pidof tcpdump)" == "" ] because it would kill the process just one second later

Answer (score 0):

Variable values are not kept between different invocation of the same script. Meaning, you can't save your program PID in a variable and expect the variable to be initialized to that value when you run the script again.

Save the PID value in a temporary file:

```
if [...] ; then
    sudo tcpdump -i eth0 ..... &
    disown
    echo $! > somefile.pid
    echo "started"
else
    cat somefile.pid | xargs -n 1 kill
    echo "stopped"
fi
```

note that this command saves the `sudo` PID, not the `tcpdump` pid, which mean that you don't need `sudo` again to kill it

Also if you want a command in background to last more than the shell executing the script you should `disown` it right after launching